# What does "sort toward" means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Challenge is the fastest track to growth, especially if we can sort toward coaching.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more information: where did the sentence come from, and what is the context? Was it written by someone with poor English skills? Almost all the occurrences of "sort towards" that I looked at in [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sort%20towards%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) use "sort" as a *noun* (meaning *kind* or *type*); the one use I found of "sort" as a *verb* was in the sense of *to rank* or *to arrange*. I suspect the use in your sentence is an error.

Comment: @Chappo:  **sort** has  meanings as a verb other than the one you found with your  google-fu.

Comment: @TRomano I'm well aware of that - I checked [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sort) before I wrote my comment, because I think it's important to rely on authoritative sources rather than guesses or invention. Do you have a special dictionary-fu that provides a suitable meaning for this particular usage of the intransitive *sort* ?

Comment: @Chappo:  **Sort *towards*** is an unusual expression, and I'm offering possible ways to understand what that author might have meant by it, comparing it to two other well-attested uses of the verb **sort** (which any decent dictionary should have) each of which takes a different preposition. Preposition use is one of the most fluid things in English.

Comment: We can't know what the expression means without more context (e.g. surrounding sentences) - but it sounds odd!

Comment: It appears to be from a self-help book called ["Thanks for the Feedback: The Science and Art of Receiving Feedback Well"](https://books.google.it/books?id=Da_KAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&lpg=PT38&dq=%22Challenge+is+the+fastest+track+to+growth,+especially+if+we+can+sort+toward+coaching%22&source=bl&ots=ldFH9B5oKQ&sig=ACfU3U3upcjKoerN76WntbAa0UM7JCXQYQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjE_uPlu_PgAhUPzYUKHXf6CbMQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Challenge%20is%20the%20fastest%20track%20to%20growth%2C%20especially%20if%20we%20can%20sort%20toward%20coaching%22&f=false). It makes no more sense in context.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess on my part, but it seems that **sort** is being used intransitively to mean something like "manage to follow a particular path" or "manage to have the Sorting Hat of Life place you".   It's the preposition **toward** in combination with modal **can** that sends me in this direction. I'm just making an attempt to understand what the author might mean, as there is no standard usage of **sort** that I'm aware of with the preposition **toward**. That said, prepositions are one of the most fluid things about English.

The phrase **sort *towards* coaching** could also be seen as a variation of the intransitive **sort with {types of people}** which means to choose to hang out with certain types of people as companions, or as a variation of **sort into {something}**, which means to fit with or to be compatible with something.

> He *sorts with* bohemian types.
>
> How does this fact *sort into* your worldview?

The modal **can** complicates things a little, but possible paraphrases might be:

*If you think you might find coaching amenable....*   (if you could enjoy coaching)

*If you can see yourself as a coach...*  (if you think coaching would be a good fit)

Comment: These anonymous downvotes without explanation are truly shite, IMO.  They do nothing more than indicate that someone out there in cyberspace doesn't like *something* about the answer but who knows what that may be? Have the courage and generosity to leave a comment.

Comment: did not downvote (and wouldn't for the small quibble i have): You marked two sentences as quotes, so it would be nice to have a source for them, should someone wish to see them 'in the wild'

Comment: @loonquawl: I don't understand "blockquote" formatting to mean exclusively "this is something I'm citing from the internet".  I use it for examples.  But if it is from the wild, I cite the source.

Comment: @Chappo: disclaimer added to first paragraph.